# TimeZone support in TimeSeries Chart

Tags: jasper-reports

I am developing TimeSeries chart of two types. One uses TimePeriod as 'Hour' and another as default which is 'Day'

Now during display of report, we want to show lables on TimeAxis taking account of Time Zone passed to report as parameter. I tried to using timeAxisLabelExpression and passed formatted date there but looks like Jasper report does not take account formatting of time using TimeZone.

The date we get from sql query (means date stored in DB) is in UTC format but it needs display as per TimeZone selected on chart's Time Axis.

Does anyone know how to achieve this in *JasperReports*?

Note: We are using 4.8.0 version of iReport to design reports.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out how to add TimeZone support in TimeSeries chart in JasperReport. JasperReport internally uses JFreeChart library to generate TimeSeries reports. There is constructor for TimeTableXYDataset class which takes TimeZone. If this constructor is used, timeZone conversion happens.

I also found out that , this support of TimeZone in TimeTableXYDataset works for JfreeChart version 1.0.14 onwards. There was [defect](http://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27989#p77970%3Chttp://www.jfree.org/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=27989%3E) associated with this in earlier versions.